# Spark application build in local server, how can we access Hive Warehouse located in HDInsight

Tags: maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea, hive, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to connect to the Hive warehouse directory located in HDInsight by using Spark **local** using IntelliJ Maven.

I am using Spark 1.6 with Scala and Maven Project.

Thrift Server details:

```
`System.setProperty("hive.metastore.uris", `"thrift://hnaz.xyz123.internal.cloudapp.net:1403")`
```

i am trying to access tables of hive warehouse.

Code :

```
package Test
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, SaveMode, sources}


object TestHive {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // get spark configuration
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("SparkHiveTest")
    conf.setMaster("local[*]")
    System.setProperty("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://hnaz.xyz123.internal.cloudapp.net:1403")
    import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
    val sc = new  SparkContext(conf)
    val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
    implicit val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val df1 = sqlContext.sql(s"use $data_profiling, sqlContext.sql("show tables")");



  }
}
```

POM Dependency:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <!-- provided -->
        </dependency>
```

it is throwing error as

```
" Error:(22, 37) not found: value data_Test
    val df1 = sqlContext.sql(s"use $data_Test, sqlContext.sql("show tables")");"

Error:(22, 74) value tables is not a member of StringContext
    val df1 = sqlContext.sql(s"use $data_Test, sqlContext.sql("show tables")");
```

Thanks a ton. i have only 1 doubt. My Spark is built on a **local server**, and **Hive is located on HDInsight**. How can i access HDInsight Hive from Local Spark. I **don't** have **Spark Cluster on HDInsight**.

**Using Client Mode.**

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** The setMaster method is used to specify a local cluster. If you want to run the application in a cluster on HDInsight, you replace the argument local[]* with the URL spark://: where and are the IP address and port number of the edge node in the cluster.

This [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-intellij-tool-plugin) demonstrates how to use the Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ plug-in to develop Apache Spark applications written in Scala, and then submit them to an HDInsight Spark cluster directly from the IntelliJ integrated development environment (IDE). You can use the plug-in in a few ways:

•   Develop and submit a Scala Spark application on an HDInsight Spark cluster.

•   Access your Azure HDInsight Spark cluster resources.

•   Develop and run a Scala Spark application locally.

**Additional details:** With Azure  HDInsight 4.0 you can [integrate Apache Spark and Apache Hive with the Hive Warehouse Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/interactive-query/apache-hive-warehouse-connector).

The Apache Hive Warehouse Connector (HWC) is a library that allows you to work more easily with Apache Spark and Apache Hive by supporting tasks such as moving data between Spark DataFrames and Hive tables, and also directing Spark streaming data into Hive tables. Hive Warehouse Connector works like a bridge between Spark and Hive. It supports Scala, Java, and Python for development.

[image]

The Hive Warehouse Connector allows you to take advantage of the unique features of Hive and Spark to build powerful big-data applications. Apache Hive offers support for database transactions that are Atomic, Consistent, Isolated, and Durable (ACID). For more information on ACID and transactions in Hive, see Hive Transactions. Hive also offers detailed security controls through Apache Ranger and Low Latency Analytical Processing not available in Apache Spark.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton. i have only 1 doubt. My Spark is built on a local server, and Hive is located on HDInsight. How can i access HDInsight Hive from Local Spark. I don't have Spark Cluster on HDInsight.

Comment: An Apache Spark cluster on HDInsight is must to run the above sample. Hope this helps.